# Count per Interval using JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a `Map<DateTime,Integer> rawCount`, which contains raw count per date (a `time-series`).

I want to construct an aggregate map which will contains count during a specific interval.

For instance, if `duration = (1000*1*60*60)` and `start = new DateTime()` this map will contains total count per hour from now to the last date in the rawCount map.

I am using `JodaTime`, as `Interval` is not Comparable and I want the Map to be ordered from the most recent to the oldest date, using a `TreeMap` is not possible.

I am confused on which `Object` will be the best for my use case (is `Interval` appropriate?) and how to write this function.

Comment: What is wrong with using a TreeMap?  I would use an `int[]` unless your data is *very* sparse as it is the most efficient by far.

Comment: You can't use a TreeMap when the Key in an Interval because you can't compare Interval between them, so when you will put new items, it will failed

Comment: You can give the TreeMap a `Comparator<Interval>` but like I said an `int[]` is far more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would solve it.

```
Map<DateTime,Integer> rawCount = ....
DateTime start = ....
long duration = 1*60*60*1000;

DateTime lastDate = start;
// find the last date
for (DateTime dateTime : rawCount.keySet()) {
    if (dateTime.isAfter(lastDate))
        lastDate = dateTime;
}
int intervals = (int) ((lastDate.getMillis() - start.getMillis())/duration) + 1;
int[] counts = new int[intervals];
for (Map.Entry<DateTime, Integer> entry : rawCount.entrySet()) {
    DateTime key = entry.getKey();
    int interval = (int) ((key.getMillis() - start.getMillis()) / duration);
    counts[interval] += entry.getValue(); 
}
```

Comment: Then how you know which count for which interval? The map allowed me to know that 'between date X and date Y the count is equal to Z'

Comment: You can compute any of the intervals. It is `start + i * duration` to `start + (i+1) * duration`

Comment: The interval number is rounded down so its technically `[start + i * duration, start + (i+1) * duration)`, inclusive/exclusive.

Comment: No. I mean here int interval = (int) ((key.getMillis() - start.getMillis()) / duration); if you try, at the first iteration interval = intervals

Comment: Good point if the difference between the start and the last date is exactly a multiple of the duration this could happen.  I have fixed it now.

Comment: if first key = lastDate then int intervals = (int) Math.ceil((lastDate.getMillis() - start.getMillis() + 1)/duration) will be equal to (int) ((key.getMillis() - start.getMillis()) / duration) as you cast into int, then we will try to insert at count.length

Comment: You should change with int intervals = (int) Math.ceil((lastDate.getMillis() - start.getMillis())/duration) + 1;

Comment: I let you edit the post and then I will accept your answer as the array of int is very efficient, sometimes we try to use big data structures for simple things...

Comment: `ceil` rounds up and `(int)` rounds down. If it make it clearer I could remove the ceil.

Comment: I really had the issue, you can try by making lastDate = firstKey in the set

Comment: ok, you changed your post, I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: My mistake. The `/ duration` does integer division so the `Math.ceil` doesn't do anything. It doesn't matter which key is the lastDate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22529/discussion-between-johnjohnga-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: ok FInally, you should keep your ceil and cast the divider by (double):  int intervals = (int) Math.ceil((end.getMillis() - start.getMillis())/(double)duration); this will fix any possible scenario

Comment: In that case you need `(int) Math.ceil((end.getMillis() - start.getMillis() + 1)/(double)duration)` in case the end - start is an exact multiple of duration e.g. if end == start.

Comment: Yep! Thanks now it is seems to be fine!